# QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput signal real time emitting

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

это мой первый пост на данном ресурсе )

Прошу помощи разобраться с непонятным поведением разрабатываемой программы на C++ и Qt5.11.2 под Windows, компилируемой MSVC17.
Основная программа (родительский процесс)  выполняет запуск стороннего приложения (процесс потомка) (.exe) с помощью использования класса QProcess. При этом в родительском процессе должен выполняться вывод на печать сообщений, которые были выведены в процессе потомка в stdout в режиме реального времени.  Код основной программы и стороннего приложения  при ведены ниже.

Суть проблемы: печать в родительском  процессе производится только один раз, хотя печать в stdout в процессе потомка производится дважды. При этом производится печать всего содержимого stdout процесса потомка и непосредственно перед изменением статуса процесса потомка с QProcess::Running на QProcess::NotRunning.

Предполагаю, что сигнал QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput() вызывается только однажды. В документации читал, что сигналы и слоты обрабатываются асинхронно, при этом сигнал QProcess::stateChanged() вызывается несколько раз, как и положено.

Пробовал, но не помогло (или плохо пробовал):

1. Запуск процесс на вызов приложения с помощью вызова C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe с параметрами "/C C:\path-to-app\child_application.exe"
2. Добавление в конструктор AppProcess строки
   _application.setReadChannelMode(QProcess::Unbuffered);
3. Добавление классу AppProcess свойства типа QThread, поручение этому дочернему потоку основного процесса обработку сигнала void AppProcess::log(const QString&)

Код программы, которая вызвана в родительском процессе.
main.cp

```
...
AppProcess application = AppProcess(cwd, applicationName, parameters);
QObject::connect(&application, &AppProcess::log, [&cp](const QString& message) {
    std::cout << "Report: " << message.toStdString();
});
application.startApp();
...
```

AppProcess.h

```
class AppProcess :
public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    AppProcess(const sfs::path& wd, const sfs::path& application,
        const QString& parameters, QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void startApp();
    void stopApp();

signals:
    void log(const QString& message);

private slots:
    void errorOccured(const QProcess::ProcessError& error);
    void readyReadStandardOutput();
    void stateChanged(const QProcess::ProcessState& newState);
    void finished(const int& exitCode, const QProcess::ExitStatus& exitStatus);

private:
    bool _listening;
    QProcess _application;

};
```

AppProcess.cpp

```
AppProcess::AppProcess(const sfs::path& wd, const sfs::path& application,
const QString& parameters, QObject *parent) : 
_application(QProcess(this)),
_listening(false)
{
    _application.setWorkingDirectory(QString(wd.string().c_str()));
    _application.setProgram(QString(application.string().c_str()));
    _application.setArguments(QStringList() << parameters);
    _application.setReadChannelMode(QProcess::SeparateChannels);
    _application.setCurrentReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);

    connect(&_application, &QProcess::errorOccurred,
        this, &AppProcess::errorOccured);
    connect(&_application, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput,
        this, &AppProcess::readyReadStandardOutput);
    connect(&_application, &QProcess::stateChanged,
        this, &AppProcess::stateChanged);

    connect(&_application, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished),
        this, &AppProcess::finished);
}

void AppProcess::startApp() 
{
    _listening = true;
    _application.start();
    _application.waitForFinished(-1);

}

void AppProcess::stopApp() 
{
    _listening = false;
    emit log("Closed by user!");
    _application.kill();
}

void AppProcess::errorOccured(const QProcess::ProcessError& error) 
{
    if (!_listening) return;
    switch (error)
    {
    case QProcess::FailedToStart:
        emit log("Failed to start");
        break;
    case QProcess::Crashed:
        emit log("Crashed");
        break;
    case QProcess::Timedout:
        emit log("TimedOut");
        break;
    case QProcess::ReadError:
        emit log("Read error");
        break;
    case QProcess::WriteError:
        emit log("Write error");
        break;
    default:
        emit log("Unknnown error");
        break;
    }
}

void AppProcess::readyReadStandardOutput() 
{
    if (!_listening) return;
    emit log(_application.readAllStandardOutput().trimmed());
}

void AppProcess::stateChanged(const QProcess::ProcessState& newState) 
{
    if (!_listening) return;
    switch (newState)
    {
    case QProcess::NotRunning:
        emit log("Not Running");
        break;
    case QProcess::Starting:
        emit log("Starting...");
        break;
    case QProcess::Running:
        emit log("Running");
        break;
    }
}

void AppProcess::finished(const int& exitCode, const QProcess::ExitStatus& exitStatus)
{
    if (!_listening) return;
    emit log("ExitCode: " + QString::fromStdString(std::to_string(exitCode)) +
        " ExitStatus: " + QString(exitStatus ? "CrashExit" : "NormalExit"));

}
```

Код программы, вызываемой в процессе потомка.
child_application.cpp

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "just a simple message\r\n";
    Sleep(10000);
    std::cout << "just a simple message\r\n";
}
```

Вывод сообщений в stdout родительского процесса,  полученных от процесса потомка.

```
Report: Starting...
Report: Running
Report: just a simple message


just a simple message
Report: Not Running
Report: ExitCode: 0 ExitStatus: NormalExit
```

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `"\r\n"` написать `<< std::endl;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поток `std::cout` при выводе буферизуется. Это значит, что данные, помещенные в поток, не сразу попадут в вызывающий процесс (или файл, или устройство вывода). А попадут они туда тогда, когда поток решит сбросить буфер. В вашем случае это происходит при завершении работы процесса.

Есть способ вручную сбросить буфер. Для этого можно вызвать функцию

```
std::cout.flush();
```

Или записать в поток символ конца строки:

```
std::cout << "just a simple message" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

@maestro, спасибо большое вам за подсказку. Однако, я хочу немного его дополнить, основываясь на произведенных тестах.

Действительно использование `std::endl` для обозначения новой строки или ручной сброс буфера потока вывода на печать с помощью `std::cout.flush()` решает проблему. Однако, достичь желаемого результата мне удалось, если после каждого сброса буфера останавливать выполнения процесса на некоторый интервал.

Привожу некоторые примеры тестов.
Код программы, вызываемой в процессе потомка. child_application.cpp

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long waitMS = 100; //10; //0;
    std::cout << "just a simple message1" << std::endl;
    Sleep(waitMS);
    std::cout << "just a simple message2" << std::endl;
    Sleep(waitMS);
    std::cout << "just a simple message3" << std::endl;
    Sleep(waitMS);
    std::cout << "just a simple message4" << std::endl;
    Sleep(waitMS);
    std::cout << "just a simple message5" << std::endl;
    Sleep(waitMS);
    std::cout << "just a simple message6" << std::endl;
    Sleep(waitMS);
    std::cout << "last message" << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод сообщений в stdout родительского процесса, полученных от процесса потомка, если waitMS=0.

```
Report: Starting...
Report: Running
Report: just a simple message1

just a simple message2

just a simple message3

just a simple message4

just a simple message5

just a simple message6

last message
Report: Not Running
Report: ExitCode: 0 ExitStatus: NormalExit
```

Вывод сообщений в stdout родительского процесса, полученных от процесса потомка, если waitMS=10.

```
Report: Starting...
Report: Running
Report: just a simple message1
Report: just a simple message2
Report: just a simple message3

just a simple message4
Report: just a simple message5

just a simple message6
Report: last message
Report: Not Running
Report: ExitCode: 0 ExitStatus: NormalExit
```

Вывод сообщений в stdout родительского процесса, полученных от процесса потомка, если waitMS=100.

```
Report: Starting...
Report: Running
Report: just a simple message1
Report: just a simple message2
Report: just a simple message3
Report: just a simple message4
Report: just a simple message5
Report: just a simple message6
Report: last message
Report: Not Running
Report: ExitCode: 0 ExitStatus: NormalExit
```

Comment: Согласно документации, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep Sleep ничего не делает с буферами, всю работу делает endl. Делать выводы о работе языка, библиотек и операционной системы на основании каких-то там тестов методически неправильно, потому как поведение может быть вызвано случайным совпадением или другими факторами. Пользуйтесь документацией на язык и операционную систему.